# CLP error when running plweb

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd, clpq

I downloaded plweb from http://www.swi-prolog.org/git/plweb.git/snapshot/7cd70cef6011b480ef05f2b8679728abba719c0c.tar.gz

```
$cd plweb-7cd70ce/
$./run 
ERROR: plweb-7cd70ce/register.pl:35:
    source_sink `library(smtp)' does not exist
Warning: plweb-7cd70ce/register.pl:35:
    Goal (directive) failed: register:use_module(library(smtp))
Warning: plweb-7cd70ce/load.pl:50:
    Using CLP(FD) with bounded arithmetic may yield wrong results.
ERROR: /home/***/swi-prolog/lib/swipl-6.2.6/library/clp/clpq/store_q.pl:347:
    evaluable `-1 rdiv _G43862' does not exist
ERROR: /home/***/swi-prolog/lib/swipl-6.2.6/library/clp/clpq/bv_q.pl:85:
    Exported procedure store_q:isolate/3 is not defined
...
```

Regards !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your question, I tried the same, from the link you supply, but got different errors: about `smtp`, try `?- pack_install(smtp).` that solved the first error for me. Then I have different problems than yours

```
?- [load].
ERROR: /home/carlo/lib/swipl-6.3.7/library/explain.pl:36:
    source_sink `library(helpidx)' does not exist
Warning: /home/carlo/lib/swipl-6.3.7/library/explain.pl:36:
    Goal (directive) failed: prolog_explain:load_files(library(helpidx),[if(changed)])
```

while you are running without GMP support. I'll try to recover helpidx.pl and I'll report the outcome, but cannot say anything about miss GMP support (I do have it).

**edit** I took the first [link](https://raw.github.com/lamby/pkg-swi-prolog/master/library/helpidx.pl) that google answer when queried 'swi-prolog generate helpidx', pasted the source in a library directory (paths inspected with `?- file_search_path(library, X).`). Then I've done:

```
?- [load].
% Library was moved: library(http/dcg_basics) --> library(dcg/basics)
% load compiled 7.36 sec, 33,882 clauses
true.
```

I think that helpidx.pl is meant to be generated, not picked from a random source.. Next I'll try to understand better the documentation server, to see if I can solve this last problem.

HTH

Comment: swipl-6.3.8 will report same error in library(clp).

Comment: but did you solved the GMP miss dependency? try installing libgmp-dev, or equivalent for your platform. See [this](http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/LinuxDistro.html) page

Comment: it works now by fixing the GMP issure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299421/how-to-enable-gmp-on-freebsd?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You also need plweb-www.git, and then need to run some install step to integrate the two.
Look in the www directory - if it's empty you need plweb-www.

I'm on another machine now, when I get back to the machine with plweb on it I'll look at how I installed.

I remember altering something in some installer-ish prolog file.

Comment: where is plweb-www.git ?

Comment: copy your checkout uri and change the end from plweb.git to plweb-www.git, then checkout into a separate directory (at same level as plweb is where I did it) - I think I had to edit the install script to point at where my plweb-www directory was